# What noteworthy contributions have Chinese AI researchers made in the field of artificial intelligence?

Tags: research, history, ai-field

In recent years, China has made rapid progress in manufacturing and scientific research, as evidenced by their successful teleportation of a single quantum entangled photon to a satellite in orbit.

My question is, what major contributions have Chinese AI researchers made in the field of Artificial Intelligence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's Baidu with former chief scientist Andrew Ng that's doing research on AI and the Microsoft Asia team has won some ImageNet competitions.